# Discrete subspace of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

Endow $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology. Does $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ contain a discrete subspace of size $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: What prevents you from chosing $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ or $\{1\} \times \mathbb N^{\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is not discrete and the latter is not a subset of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. The latter should be a subset, though: If we see $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ as $\{f | f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\}$ then the subset is the set such that $f(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{N}$ is separable (with the discrete topology), we have that $\mathbb{N}^{{\mathbb{N}}}$ is separable with the product topology. Therefore, any subspace is separable, so there is no discrete subspace of cardinal $2^{\aleph_{0}}$

Comment: No, a subspace of a separable space need *not* be separable in general. A correct argument is that $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is second countable, and so will all its subspaces be. $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}$ is also separable and has many discrete subspaces of size continuum.

Comment: Of course, we used the fact that $\mathbb{N}^{{\mathbb{N}}}$ is a numerable product of separable metric spaces, and therefore, it's a separable metric space

Comment: Yes, but your argument as stated is false. You should make the second countable (which follows from separable + metric) the crux, not the separability.